# Pywinauto click on item in submenu of context menu?

Tags: pywinauto

Trying to achieve this 
[image: Trying to achieve this]

One level till send to menu I am able to click but after that I am not able to click.

I'm getting an error as;

> pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'BTDecoder' in
>   'dict_keys(['Open', 'MenuItem', 'OpenMenuItem', 'MenuItem0',
>   'MenuItem1', 'MenuItem2', 'Protect with RMS'

```
app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe", title="FW")

#app.path.set_focus()
common_files = app.FW.ItemsView.get_item('WRT_FW_6_3_2019_10_37_56_multi_core_000001.etl')
common_files.set_focus().click_input(button='left')
common_files.click_input(button='right')
#pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia").FW.print_control_identifiers()
app.ContextMenu.wait('visible', timeout=10)
app.ContextMenu.child_window(title="Send to", control_type="Menu").click_input()
app.ContextMenu.wait('visible', timeout=10)
app.ContextMenu.child_window(title="BTDecoder", auto_id="31014",control_type="MenuItem").click_input()
```

Comment: app.ContextMenu.child_window(title="Send to", control_type="Menu").click_input() is not working we have to use control_type="MenuItem"

Comment: If the problem is solved, can you post this as an answer and accept it? It's OK to accept your own answer (gray check box under voting buttons at the left side of the answer).

Comment: Hi Vasily the problem is still there after clicking on the sen to i am not able to click the sub-menu items